# Textures getting messed up when exporting fbx

Tags: texture-painting

I'm working on my very first character model, and decided to texture paint the hair in its own file to keep things tidy. Inside its file it looks fine...
[image]

But when I import it as an fbx into the file that contains the body, the textures don't seem to be loading properly, and also inexplicably have a glassy, transparent look to them.
[image]
[image]

Any idea as to why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: This can happen when having multiple UV maps on your objects because some software just used the first UV map, not the UV map specified in your material. So try and delete any unused UV maps if you have any.

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any extras? There's only one uv map per object as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hello did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue and I only have one UV as well. granted the UV has updated about 10 or so times through the editing process, there is still only 1 UV being used. Maybe I'm missing something?